# Darlington Transistor Array

Tags: transistors, led-matrix

I am Making an 8x8 Led Dot Matrix Display following this guide https://www.insidegadgets.com/2010/11/07/fun-with-8x8-led-matrix/ as you can see it requires a "ULN2803A Darlington Array (of Transistors)" I need to make this Project now and i dont have time to order the IC. Is it possible to make the required IC using Transistors. If so do i need special ones or can i use anyone Such as the 2N3904

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just copy the circuit inside the ULN2803 using (lots of) discrete parts.

[image]

For push-pull drive from the micro and LED drive you can probably leave out the diode (and the parasitic diodes with the dashed lines, of course), as well as the 3K and 7.2K resistors, so just the two transistors and the base resistor.

The maximum current will be set by the transistor Ic(max), for the 2N3904 that's only 200mA. The ULN2803 is good for 500mA, but whatever your requirements are.. you could use a 2N4401 and either another 2N4401 or a 2N4401 and a 2N3904.

Edit: Given the schematic in the link, you don't need to duplicate the current capability of the ULN2803. A single transistor with a 510 ohm base resistor (assuming 5V drive) should suffice, so 8 transistors and 8 resistors. The maximum collector current is about 120mA (at 12.5% duty cycle) so a 2N3904 or 2N4401 per channel will do.

Comment: So Basically Make this 8 times ? http://i.imgur.com/5R08oFz.png

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: Now I know you where talking about current Do you think theses can provide enough current for a 8x8 red led matrix

Comment: @liljoey112 - please provide a part number for the transistors you are considering.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It would be the 2N3904. Also What do you think of using the Single Transistor

Comment: Without knowing how much current you wish to draw, there is no way to answer your question. How much current, in mA, does each driver need to handle? Not average, but rather worst case. Now look at a 2N3904 data sheet. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It says Max Current is 200ma And one led is 20ma So its safe to assume that its okay?

Comment: It will be OK at 20 mA with a single 2N3904 as long as you use about a 1k base resistor. Since any individual LED will only be on 1/8th of the time, your array will not be as bright as you think.

Comment: Looking at your source schematic, the peak current through each transistor is about 120mA (assuming all 8 HC595 outputs are high), so a darlington of 2N3904s or single transistors, but I'd use about a 510 ohm base resistor.

Answer (score 1):

The page you link above has this note following the last photo:

> Edit: I’ve been advised that you don’t actually need a Darlington
>   array for this, you could use the second shift register to become the
>   ground. Shifting a 1 would disable the ground and shifting a 0 would
>   enable ground.

Or, since the Darlingtons would only be driving one LED at a time, it should be possible to replace the ULN2803 with eight 2N3094 transistors, with a 1K or so base resistor for each transistor, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f82OQ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain more

Comment: Besides using less parts and easier construction does this method have any draw backs?

Comment: I can't think of any drawbacks.