# darlington transistor led matrix

Tags: arduino, decoder, led-matrix, darlington

I want to run an 8x8 led matrix by using a darlington transistor arduino and decoder. for some reference I was looking at this previous question([Darlington Transistor Array](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180798/darlington-transistor-array)). Each of my Leds draws 100mA, I know that the objective of using a darlington transistor is to supply a high current to the pins but how is this doing so if the darlington is being turned on to ground the Led and the decoder to give the Led voltage. Am I going to draw too much current from the arduino pin? How is the darlington working in this case to prevent from drawing too much current from the arduino?

Comment: huh? what decoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save some money and buy ULN2003 Darlington arrays as a SOIC or a dip package. They have base resistors and clamp diodes built in. At 7 per array you will need 3 of them, but they save much space anyways. They also have in-line pin outs so board layout is easy.

I created a schematic the best I could. I cannot find one that shows all 7 in one package, but I hope this helps you with assembly. The upper section drives the positive voltage to the LED, while the lower section grounds the LED cathode. 8 x 8 = 64 LED's. Note that R2 may have to be reduced to 22 ohms if LED current is 100 mA. Also R3 may get hot at 100 mA but that is ok.

NOTE: You can skip the Darlington if V+ is the same as the MPU V+, but it maybe difficult to push 100 mA through and LED if V+ is only 3.3 volts. In which case you will need to keep the Darlington in place and make V+ 5 volts or more (Keep the Arduino at 3.3 volts). The LED turn-on voltage is about 2.95 volts, and the transistor will cause a 1.5 volt drop, so V+ may have to be 5 volts.

Here is a link to the ULN2000 series: http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/interfaces-and-transceivers/darlington-arrays/uln2003.html

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7etGE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: sorry need some terminology clarifications. what is a SOIC or a dip package? also I bought some ULN2003APG but the output is inverted so they are grounded. Why would I only need 3 of the darlington? How would I just used the darlingtons as appose to including the decoder? How would i be getting a voltage coming in if they go to ground when a current is sent to them?

Comment: should have got `ULN2803` as they have 8 channels instead of 7, but if they were cheap and you have room to fit the extra parts it's not that bad.

Comment: There are only 7 to a package, so if you need 16 open-collector outputs you will need 3 of these ULN2003's. You will have surplus, but that's how it goes. A positive input turns on the transistor, so its output is grounded.

Comment: see wikipedia for SOIC and DIP

Comment: NOTE: Pin #8 is ground for all 7 transistors.

Comment: sorry I am still confused. yes a positive input turns the transistor to ground but if I am using one transistor for the column and one for the row how do I turn on the LED if there is no positive voltage going through the transistor only turning the transistor from off to grounded

Comment: Sorry if answer was not complete. You need 8 PNP transistors, 2N3906 will do, to convert 8 ULN2003 outputs to source your voltage. Don't forget each LED needs a resistor of 330 ohms or so, or they will burn up. Wish I could make a schematic, but those IC's are not in our parts library.

Comment: so basically your saying if I stick with using the ULN2003 because it's output are grounded I will need to send the outputs through a transistor that has a positive voltage? I can't just used an inverter right? because they don't output high current?

Comment: I created a schematic the best I could. I cannot find one that shows all 7 in one package, but I hope this helps you with assembly. The upper section drives the positive voltage to the LED, while the lower section grounds the LED cathode. 8 x 8 = 64 LED's.

Comment: @sparky need a resistor between 2n2904 and ULN2003

Comment: @Jasen. Thanks for catching that. Not always an issue, but it can be if thermal runaway condition.

Comment: @sparky, without that you're short circuiting the powersupply., PNP emitter, PNP pbase, ULN2003 collector

Comment: It will work st fine. Built many of them. In bed. Goodnight.

Comment: thank you very much! do I really need to add the darlington to the row? Can't I just use the 2N3906 alone?

Comment: Yes, *if V+ is the same as the MPU V+*. Also, the MPU pin would have to be 'low' to turn on a PNP. Keep the 2.2 K and 1K resistor, but eliminate the Darlington. When the MPU boots up, it should make those pins 'high' first, until your LED program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Arduinos can only supply about 20mA per pin, so yes 100mA is too much, and you need 8 of therm (each row) so 800mA total.

So the `ULN2803` to power the columns and need to also use darlingtons to power the columns, 
this will need to be a source type like `M54564`

Comment: does that transistor output as a ground or as a positive? I just bought a bunch of ULN2003APG transistors.

Comment: it's a positive output when on.

Comment: @Jasen. The ULN2003 output is open collector, so when ON it grounds the collector. Also known as active-low outputs.

Comment: wait so are they positive output or grounded?

Comment: `ULN2x03` is grounded when on `M54564` is positive when on

Comment: ok thank you! so I can just switch the decoder and transistor process and then it should work right?

Comment: also in your answer did you mean the "ULN2803 to power the columns and need to also use darlingtons to power the rows?" so use two different darlingtons?

Comment: I would expect so, I'm not sure what exactly what your setup is, or what the decoder is - is it the arduino?

Comment: two darlingon arrays?, yes! if the LEDs take 100mA each you'll need beefy drive on both rows and columns

Comment: Jason i'm still a little confused why I would need them for both the row and column. Do you have any reference material I can look at for understanding that?

Comment: with the M54564 how can I figure out the minimum voltage supply that's needed and where does it say on the datasheet that it outputs positive?

Comment: positive because It says "source" (also I looked at the circuit diagram.)  In `ELECTRICAL CHARACTERISTICS` it says that at 100mA supply should be at-least 2V above the output voltage (1.45V is typical but it could be as bad as 2V)

Comment: THE M54564 cannot drive 8 outputs at 100mA at 100% duty cycle. P : no more than 55%, FP : no more than 30%.  and it is non-inverting. ULN200x can only do 50% duty cycle at 100mA and is inverting. No good But you can gang 2

Comment: do you know of any other darlington transistors that don't invert, or some key terms I can google to find them? I want to try and order one on amazon and M54564 isn't on there.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 , good catch, perhaps need to use two M54564 in parallel (split the LED resistor),  the other side is harder  what can handle 800mA ?  that's like 1W dissipation in a darlington.  - maybe 8 times BD678  with 330 ohm base resistors.

Comment: Any transistor (single or Darlington, and NPN or PNP) will invert when used in a common emitter circuit (for NPN, that is with the emitter connected to Ground).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use one of your Arduino's SPI ports, or generate SPI in software by manipulating its GPIO ('bit banging'), then you could use the ONSemi NCV7608.

Its logic inputs are high impedance so you're only drawing tiny signal and switching currents from your Arduino SPI/GPIO pins.

Note that the NCV7608 load voltage (VS) range is 5.5 V to 28 V, so this device is only viable if your LED supply voltage rail can be in that range.

The NCV7608 gives you 8 configurable 350 mA drivers, each of which can be a low-side or high-side driver. You can use low-side drivers with an external clamp diode across each of your relays. Driver 'on' resistance is 1.2 ohms, giving a low driver power dissipation than the Darlington ULN2003A etc.

The device has a logic supply and a load power supply. The logic supply range is 3.15 V to 5.25 V, so it'll interface directly to your 3.3 V logic.

It also has over-current protection and some error-detection functions thrown in that you can access over the SPI interface.

[image]

You can then use 2 x NCV7608 devices and 8 x LED resistor to drive your 8x8 LED matrix.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fftANz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 provides the 8 high-side drivers for the LED array that connect each column of LED anodes to the LED supply voltage via a current-limiting series resistor. U2 provides the 8 low-side drivers that connect each row of LED cathodes to GND.

LED series resistors R1..R8 are all the same value. Each NCV7608 driver adds 1.2 R to the LED series resistance, making this resistance 2.4 R plus the resistor value. The series resistance, the Vled supply voltage, LED voltage drop at your drive current and Ohm's Law all determine the LED current when lit. For example, a Vled supply of 6 V and an LED drop of 1.6 V @ 100 mA lead to a 39 R series resistors

(from R= V/I = (6-1.6)/0.1 = 44 R, minus 2.4 R is 41.6 R, use standard 39 R)

U1 and U2 use one SPI port with two chip selects to select the target SPI device. This SPI port is either a hardware one in your Arduino or one implemented by a software routine controlling GPIO ports.

Your Arduino software can then implement a scanning routine, writing to the SPI ports for U1 and U2. This routine would repeatedly select one new column only then drive each of the rows, one at a time, with their display data and wait for an LED lighting period. There is plenty of text driving on multiplexed LED displays on the internet.